# WordPress - Custom Taxonomies on CPT aren't displaying correctly

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type called 'activity' and a custom taxonomy called 'category_activity'.

On single-activity.php I am wanting to display the current taxonomy. At the moment, all taxonomies are being displayed even if they aren't added to the post.

single-activity.php:

```
$taxonomy = 'category_activity';
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
if ( $terms ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) { echo $term->name; }
}
```

Should display: 'Taxonomy Name 1'

Currently displays: 'Taxonomy Name 1 Taxonomy Name 2 Taxonomy Name 3'.

Taxonomy registration:

```
function cptui_register_my_taxes_category_activity() {

$labels = array(
    "name" => __( 'Things Categories', '' ),
    "singular_name" => __( 'Things Category', '' ),
);

$args = array(
    "label" => __( 'Things Categories', '' ),
    "labels" => $labels,
    "public" => true,
    "hierarchical" => true,
    "label" => "Things Categories",
    "show_ui" => true,
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
    "query_var" => true,
    "rewrite" => array( 'slug' => 'things-to-do/category', 'with_front' => false, ),
    "show_admin_column" => false,
    "show_in_rest" => false,
    "rest_base" => "",
    "show_in_quick_edit" => false,
);
register_taxonomy( "category_activity", array( "activity" ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_taxes_category_activity' );
```

Thanks for the help.

EDIT - I got this working with:

```
$category = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'category_activity');
echo $category[0]->name;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to use wp_get_post_terms in your case :
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms

```
<?php $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy, $args ); ?>
```